# Intellij IDEA: newline after specific tag (br)

Tags: html, intellij-idea, formatting

Is there a way to create a newline after a specific tag, in my case e.g. after every `<br>`? I've searched the settings under "Editor | Code Style | HTML | Other", but couldn't find it...

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option, please vote for [WEB-5182](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-5182/Settings-Code-style-HTML-Insert-new-line-after-could-be-introduced) to raise its priority and get notified on updates